# Create a firebase key using a previous timestamp

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-platform

I understand Firebase Realtime Database push() auto-creates a unique key using the current timestamp to make sure chronological ordered. I would like to know if there is a way to create a key using a previous timestamp (for example, 6 months ago), to basically get a key that I would have gotten using push() 6 months ago.

Answer (score 1):

> I understand firebase push() auto-creates a unique key using the current timestamp to make sure chronological ordered.

Yes, you're right. The pushed IDs contain a time component. As Michael Lehenbauer mentioned in this blog [article](https://firebase.blog/posts/2015/02/the-2120-ways-to-ensure-unique_68):

> Push IDs are string identifiers that are generated client-side. They are a combination of a timestamp and some random bits. The timestamp ensures they are ordered chronologically, and the random bits ensure that each ID is unique, even if thousands of people are creating push IDs at the same time.

And to answer your question:

> I would like to know if there is a way to create a key using a previous timestamp (for example, 6 months ago)

That's currently not possible. If you want to generate random IDs of your choice, in which each ID is based on the timestamp that is present in the previous one, then you should create your own mechanism.

However, you can continue using those pushed IDs but you can create a timestamp field, in which you can add a timestamp value of your choice. Then you can order the results either ascending (which is the default one) or descending if you need that.

**Edit:**

After seeing @RenaudTarnec suggestion and @FrankvanPuffelen [solution](https://gist.github.com/puf/82bf5abb69f5399a1380f6f0160aba6d), it turns out that you can create a "fake" pushed ID based on the actual algorithm.

Comment: Hi @AlexMamo, maybe it is possible to create a "fake" push ID based on a specific date/timestamp through the algorithm used to create them: https://gist.github.com/mikelehen/3596a30bd69384624c11. By adapting the line `var now = new Date().getTime();`

Comment: @RenaudTarnec Yes, it most likely can be done. But that means that the OP will not use the original algorithm, provided by the SDK, but his own mechanism.

Comment: I'm with Renaud here and think this would actually be pretty straightforward to do. Take the code, set your own timestamp, voila: same algorithm, different _implementation_.

Comment: Took me a while, but then I recalled where I'd done this before: https://gist.github.com/puf/82bf5abb69f5399a1380f6f0160aba6d

Comment: @RenaudTarnec I've seen your comment right when you wrote it and didn't see the later edit. Thanks for the suggestion, you're right.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Thanks again, puf. I know I also saw [it](https://gist.github.com/puf/82bf5abb69f5399a1380f6f0160aba6d) before. Makes sense.